# operation history C#

Tags: c#, generics, calculator

Hello i have question I just start my adventure with c# and I have question I want to do history of calculator operation my code works but I want to do history of last 10 operation but It show only last operation

```
public class CalculationHistory
    {
        public CalculationHistory()
        {
            Items = new List<CalculationHistoryItem>();
        }

        public List<CalculationHistoryItem> Items { get; set; }

        public void Add(double x, double y, string z)
        {
            Items.Add(new CalculationHistoryItem(x, y, z));
        }

    }

    public class CalculationHistoryItem
    {
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public string z { get; set; }

        public CalculationHistoryItem(double first, double sec, string res)
        {
            x = first;
            y = sec;
            z = res;
        }
    }
```

Here, the rest of the code that is supposed to display the last 10 operations after the "p" key, but it shows only the last thing I need to change to start working properly

```
case "P":
                        Console.WriteLine("Lista ostatnich operacji : ");
                        CalculationHistory history = new CalculationHistory();
                        history.Add(x, y, z);
                        foreach (var item in history.Items)
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        break;
```

Comment: That's because you are creating a new history instead of using an existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that for each new calculation operation, you create a new "CalculationHistory" object. Therefore each CalculationHistory object keeps its own history.

Solution: define an object outside the loop

```
CalculationHistory history = new CalculationHistory();
```

Add to the same object for each action.

```
Console.WriteLine("Lista ostatnich operacji : ");
history.Add(x, y, z);
foreach (var item in history.Items)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
break;
```